# Is it possible to access a private struct field from a test?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm learning Rust at the moment (1 week so far) and I want to test my code.

I have this struct:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
  pub field1: i64,
  field2: i64
}

impl MyStruct {
  pub fn new(a: i64) -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct { field1: a, field2: 0 }
  }
}
```

Now in a test in another module, I want to create a `MyStruct` with a specific `field2`, but it is private.

Is there a way to do it without creating a special constructor for `MyStruct`?

Comment: Tests follow the same rules as other code.  If they're not in the same module or a descendant, they can't see private things.

Comment: if it's a unit test, shouldn't it be in the same module? otherwise it seems like you actually need a constructor. That said, the fairly new `pub(restricted)` feature might be useful. https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1422-pub-restricted.md

Comment: @the8472: I'm testing a module that use this one. I'm not aware of mocking capabilities in Rust, it's the way I'd done it with Google Test in C++ :) Gonna check this feature, running nightly anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

You can write unit test in the same module or create submodule for tests. Code in the same module and in all nested modules has full access to private fields.

```
// Your struct

mod test {
    use super::MyStruct;
    fn test() {
        let _ = MyStruct{ field1: 1, field2: 2 };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to say that the test using the struct is in another module. Edited to add this info.

Comment: Consider also adding `#[cfg(test)]` to the test module,  so as to only be considered in the testing phase.